# React server side rendering page source is not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

I'm working with server side rendering for my React Js App.showing page content and routes are working fine.but when i hit 'page source',it's not showing all content inside html.also when i navigate to another page and hit 'page source',it's not updated old html.
Any idea about this issue?

**server.js**

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import express from 'express';
import { matchRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import Routes from './client/Routes';
import renderer from './helpers/renderer';
import createStore from './helpers/createStore';
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const store = createStore(req);
  const promises = matchRoutes(Routes, req.path)
    .map(({ route }) => {
      return route.loadData ? route.loadData(store) : null;
    })
    .map(promise => {
      if (promise) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          promise.then(resolve).catch(resolve);
        });
      }
    });

  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    const context = {};
    const content = renderer(req, store, context);
    res.send(content);
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on prot 3000');
});
```

**renderer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import serialize from 'serialize-javascript';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import Routes from '../client/Routes';

export default (req, store, context) => {
  const content = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={context}>
        <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  );

  const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();

  return `<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>      
        ${helmet.title.toString()}
        ${helmet.meta.toString()}        
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${content.toString()}</div>
        <script>
          window.INITIAL_STATE = ${serialize(store.getState())}
        </script>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
};
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import { fetchHomeSliders } from './actions/home';
const App = ({ route }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {renderRoutes(route.routes)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default {
  component: App,
  loadData: ({ dispatch }) => dispatch(fetchHomeSliders())
};
```

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import HomePage from './components/home';
import About from './components/about';

export default [
  {
    ...App,
    routes: [
      {
        ...HomePage,
        path: '/',
        exact: true
      }
      ,
      {
        ...About,
        path: '/about-us'
      }

    ]
  }
];
```

**fetchHomeSliders API**

```
 export const fetchHomeSliders = () => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
      const request = await api.get(`https://example.com/api/contents/ABOUT`);  
      dispatch ({type: FETCH_HOME_SLIDERS, payload: request});
      console.log("request request",request)
      };
```

Comment: It might get override during client renderring.

Comment: `inspect element` show all html code.but not in `page source`

Comment: Can you tell which content is different in inspect and page source?

Comment: `${content.toString()}` content empty when page source.but showing in inspect element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it might be happening is that on doing `view page source` only the server rendered page is shown in SSR website.
So anything you do on the client like add an html element or listener will be seen only it the inspect element.The inspect
element is kind of dynamic meaning that it updates itself to server as well as client side changes.So whenever you are doing anything like 
show/hide a div/button, it will be shown in the inspect element. Whereas when you try to `View page souce` what happens is it hits the server and 
whatever  HTML content the server returned it will show.

As an example you can check https://preactjs.com/. If you do `View page souce` in it the html content is very less and won't contain 
majority of elements compared to `inspect element`.So here only a part of the html is sent by Server and majority of things happen on 
client side.

For your case I think you need to hydrate elements rendered by server.It will ensure that the content is the same on 
the server and the client and won't override it.

Something like

```
import React from 'react'
import {hydrate} from 'react-dom'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './redux/configureStore'
import App from './components/app'
const state = window.__STATE__;
delete window.__STATE__;
const store = configureStore(state)

//Here we are hydrating.
hydrate(
    <Provider store={store} >
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#app')
)
```

Also you can check in network request if server is returning `content.toString()`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.this is solve my issue.i forgot to `hydrate` it